# why the "infinite" for loop is not processed?

Tags: go

I need to wait until x.Addr is being updated but it seems the for loop is not run. I suspect this is due the go scheduler and I'm wondering why it works this way or if there is any way I can fix it(without channels).

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

type T struct {
    Addr *string
}

func main() {

    x := &T{}
    go update(x)
    for x.Addr == nil {
        if x.Addr != nil {
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}

func update(x *T) {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    y := ""
    x.Addr = &y
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two (three) problems with your code.

First, you are right that there is no point in the loop at which you give control to the scheduler and such it can't execute the update goroutine. To fix this you can set `GOMAXPROCS` to something bigger than one and then multiple goroutines can run in parallel.

(However, as it is this won't help as you pass x by value to the update function which means that the main goroutine will never see the update on x. To fix this problem you have to pass x by pointer. Now obsolete as OP fixed the code.)

Finally, note that you have a data race on `Addr` as you are not using atomic loads and stores.

Comment: Does the number of "infinite" for loops depend by the GOMAXPROCS value? e.g. if GOMAXPROCS == 3 then we can use 2 Infinite loops?

Comment: @AnthonyHunt GOMAXPROCS determines the number of OS threads that execute user level code concurrently. So yes, you could have two infinite loops. However, you shouldn't depend on any of that and rather design your code in a way such that this craftery is not needed.